# Why android multidex support library doesn't follow support library version number?

Tags: android, android-support-library

If we download all the android support library via sdk manager in one pack (current version 23.0.1). Why all the libraries doesn't follow this version number?

For instance I thought I could use com.android.support:multidex:23.0.1 , but it is not the case!

In this subject, so, how can I really check each last version by packname?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an answer, but looking at android library page you can see all libraries other than multidex follow support library version number https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: Not every library, if you check CardView and Preference for instance, you'll see they show different versions. But I think they didn't update the page! :)

Comment: Yes, they didn't update the page otherwise you can use latest support library version.